# Order of Signatures in Multisig-Scheme

Tags: transactions, wallet, multi-signature, signature

3 Entities (A/B/C) create a collaborative Multisig Wallet (e.g. 2-of-3).

A creates an unsigned TX and shares it with B/C. They (B/C) sign and broadcast.

Looking at the TX on the network, can A make any difference who signed first? So, are signatures in the signing process appended to each other OR do they follow the specific order the multisig-setup was initially constructed?

Answer (score 3):

In the context of `OP_CHECKMULTISIG`, the signatures must appear in the same order as the public keys are listed.

The signers can create the signatures in a different order than that, but since the signature order must adhere to the original output script the order of creation cannot carry over to the final transaction.